# HtmlTextBlock: app crashes with invalid html

Tags: c#, html, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I use [HtmlTextBlock](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Krempel.WP7/1.1.0) from Krempel's WP7 Library in Windows Phone 8 app.

xaml

```
xmlns:html="clr-namespace:Krempel.WP7.Core.Controls;assembly=Krempel.WP7.Core"

<html:HtmlTextBlock Name="HtmlText"></html:HtmlTextBlock>
```

cs

```
  try
  {
     HtmlText.Html = "<a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com\">Stack Overflow</a>";
  }
  catch (Exception ex) { }
```

In this case it's work.

But if run this code then I get exception:

```
  try
  {
     HtmlText.Html = "<a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com\"><br/></a>";
  }
  catch (Exception ex) 
  {
      //not handled
  }
```

Exception:

```
Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

[image]

And I can't handle the exception in try catch. It handled in

```
  private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                Debugger.Break();
            }
        }
```

Can I validate a html string before setting HtmlTextBlock that avoid throwing the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the HTMLTextBlock from [MSP Toolkit](https://msptoolkit.codeplex.com/) instead